Animation to Unity with Constraint
So I made a character and an animation, and that character is stirring a spoon. I added that spoon as a constraint to the hand that stirs, but now in unity the spoon does not move when the animation is imported in. I have then tried baking the animation but I just get similiar results.
What would be the best way of doing this animation so that I can import it through to unity?
Thank you




Preamble: your objects have unapplied scales, this can lead to some issues, especially when exporting or baking animation. To fix this:

↹ Tab into Object Mode
Select all the mesh objects (not the armature)
In the dope sheet editor, delete all keyframes
Select all objects with A
In the viewport, press ⎈ CtrlA > Apply Scale


You can't export constraints relationships.
What you need to do is bake the spoon's animation with Visual Keying, Clear Parent and Clear Constraints enabled. This way it will bake the animation resulting of the constraint. But do this in a separate file, because it will remove the constraint and make the animation hard to revision.
To do this in your case:

↹ Tab into Object Mode

select the spoon object-

open the Operator Searchbar with F3 and search for "Bake Action".

Make sure these options are checked and press Ok:



Now, usually that's all you need to do. But for some reason in your case, the baked animation have a Y rotation offset after the first keyframe:

To fix this:

Open the Graph Editor
Select the Y Rotation channel on the left sidebar and press ⇧ ShiftH to hide all other channels' curves
Select all except the first keyframe of the curve, as I did above
Press GY180⏎ Enter to move these keys up 180⁰

This should do the trick.

Thank you for your response, unfortunately I'm still having a bit of trouble. Just so I have this right though here is what I have done so far. I created my character and have a metarig with bones and all named Correctly. Then I added a spoon as a constraint to the character, vertex group being the right hand. As I then aniamted my character the spoon moved with the right hand (should the spoon be parented to the rig also?) So now all animation data is only through the metarig, the spoon. How would I bake the animation for the spoon? Thank you again

Firstly, I have to say that the metarig isn't meant for animation, it's a placement tool to generate an animation rig. As for the rest, I don't fully understand exactly how you rigged the spoon, so I think it would greatly help if you could [edit] your question and share your blend file with us so that we can see by ourselves how things are and give the appropriate answer.

Thank you. Unfortunately things went so far wrong that I had to create a new file, but this is a close approximation to how things were, just a slightly less accurate actual animation. Thank you.

I edited my answer, it should work as is.

Thank you very much for you help and your time especially. Unfortunately I am just running into problem after problem. I'll try to strengthen my understanding on animating in blender, and exporting to unity and try from scratch again. Thank you
